# Como utilizar roles en Spring Security sin quemarlos en codigo?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Una duda, estoy utilizando Spring boot y Spring Security pero si quiero asignar roles a mis usuarios tengo que en cada microservicio poner la siguiente anotacion:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
```

Tambien lo he visto en el WebConfig pero es un poco de lo mismo.
No hay otra forma de hacer esto sin tener que manejarlo en codigo? una base de datos por ejemplo?

Comment: Tienes que crearte una tabla de usuarios y una de roles (es lo mismo que authoritys en esencia). Spring se encarga de leer que roles pueden pasar tomando el usuario logueado o el usuario anónimo.

Comment: Ok, pero y como le especifico a Spring que este rol tiene acceso a estos microservicios y a estos otros no?

Comment: La anotación que tienes lee automáticamente los roles del usuario, si no tiene el que definiste te retorna un 403. Checa esto: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: Listo, si entiendo, pero y si no lo quiero hacer asi? con anotaciones, no hay una forma que lo consulte desde una base de datos?

Comment: En realidad la anotación utiliza hibernate para consultar los roles del usuario, hacerlo de otra manera es como rehacer la rueda (En este caso y con Spring).  Aparte, la seguridad de spring es bastante robusta y define ciertos modos de trabajar para evitar brechas de seguridad, hacer cambios dentro de esta puede provocar  fallos graves en tu aplicación. (Tal Vez ahora no lo necesites pero siempre es bueno tener buenas prácticas). Al principio spring es engorroso y tiene una curva de aprendizaje bastante pesada, pero despues es muy fácil. Te recomiendo veas los tutoriales de spring.

Comment: @Angel Vale gracias, si ya veo lo de la curva de aprendizaje, me ha costado bastante. Te agradezco la aclaración, seguire mirando más acerca de Spring Security.